# standard deviation for Siamese Network

Tags: standard-deviation

If I have a Siamese network that takes a input as pairs, for example`my_input = ( Total_examples, 2, frame number , hight, width, channel)` , my questions are

1. Should I calculate the mean and standard deviation for the whole data as one set , or calculate the mean and std for each side alone, i.e. for `input1= my_input[:, 0, :, :, :, :]` and for `input2= my_input[:, 2, :, :, :, :]`.
2. If I am using pre-train network on image-net and I am fine tune it on  different dataset( face-dataset) should I depend on std of Imagenet or my dataset?
3. My dataset is very large, and for mean calculation and standard deviation calculation, I calculated the sum of example and sum of  `example - mean` for each batch. My question is I tried two experiments to see if the value is accurate , One on dataset of 500 examples  and calculate the mean and std directly on whole data, and second experiment  on batches of this dataset like 100 example at a time, and I notices that the mean and std will be different if I used `dtype = np.float32` or less in `np.sum` operation  , and it will be the same if I am using `dtype= npfloat.64` or `np.flot128`. And I know that the reason for that difference is due to precision and overflow. So Is that mean If I have large dataset and would like to do some operation on stream of data that I should use `np.float64` instead of `np.float.32` in sum operation?